# Write lists to csv file list index out of range python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Following a tutorial on youtube I could try those lines (Those lines worked for once)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

source = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Laptops&ref=nb_sb_noss_2', headers = headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

# print(soup.prettify())

Names = []
Prices = []

# for loop

for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal'):
    string = i.text
    Names.append( string.strip() )

for i in soup.find_all('span', class_='a-price-whole'):
    Prices.append(i.text)


file_name = 'Laptops.csv'

with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Sr.No', 'Laptop Name', 'Prices'])

    for i in range(len(Names)):
        #print(i, Names[i], Prices[i])
        writer.writerow([i, Names[i], Prices[i]])
```

But when trying to run it again I got the following error:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
31     for i in range(len(Names)):
32         #print(i, Names[i], Prices[i])
---> 33         writer.writerow([i, Names[i], Prices[i]])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: There are most likely less `Prices` than `Names`. Try printing out `len(Names)` and `len(Prices)` before writing the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Names` are of different length than `Prices`.

You might want to try `itertools.zip_longest()`.

Here's how:

```
import itertools

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
}

url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Laptops&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

Names = [
    i.getText(strip=True) for i in
    soup.find_all('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal')
]
Prices = [
    i.getText(strip=True) for i in
    soup.find_all('span', class_='a-price-whole')
]

with open("Laptops.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    data = list(
        itertools.zip_longest(
            list(range(1, len(Names) + 1)),
            Names,
            Prices,
            fillvalue="N/A",
        )
    )
    w.writerows(data)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your result might be differing in lenghts.

Run your loop only till smaller one.

```
for i in range(min(len(Prices),len(Names))):
```

Comment: `for i, (name, price) in enumerate(zip(Names, Prices)):`

Comment: Nice! Did not know zip takes care of lengths!